# Debug Mode to Production Mode with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, web.xml, production

I have an application Spring-Boot with Vaadin.
I finalize the implementation and I want to put the app in production.
When I launch the program, the shell writes this message :

```
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
```

Therefore, I guess I should change the web.xml file. But, the problem ; with Spring, I have not web.xml. Therefore, how can I put the productionMode to true in another way ?
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can set most (but not all) of the servlet properties by adding them to your application.properties file. You can find the supported properties [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/VaadinSpringTips.html).

```
vaadin.servlet.resourceCacheTime
vaadin.servlet.productionMode
vaadin.servlet.heartbeatInterval
vaadin.servlet.closeIdleSessions
```

Comment: It seems to be the solution ! Thank you !

Comment: The link is broken, can you update that link or tell how you get there? Thx in advance! *EDIT:* Found it [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/VaadinSpringTips.html)